# How to test a module using jest which imports an external library which is a constructor

Tags: javascript, node.js, testing, jestjs, pdfmake

I'm using a library, "pdfmake" and I want to write test cases using jest. 
I have a module pdf. Inside module pdf I'm exporting 2 functions. In  both the exports, I'm using internal functions of "pdfmake" to generate pdfs.

Here is the code snippet: 
`pdf.js`

```
const PdfPrinter = require("pdfmake");
const fonts = require("./../shared/fonts");

const printer = new PdfPrinter(fonts);

const intiateDocCreation = docDefinition =>
  printer.createPdfKitDocument(docDefinition);

const finishDocCreation = (pdfDoc, pdfStream) => {
  pdfDoc.pipe(pdfStream);
  pdfDoc.end();
};
module.exports = {
  intiateDocCreation,
  finishDocCreation
};
```

I tried using

```
const PdfPrinter = require("pdfmake");
jest.mock("pdfmake", () => {
  return {
    createPdfKitDocument: jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => ({ a: "b" }))
  };
});

describe("test", () => {
  test("pdf", () => {
    const printer = new PdfPrinter(fonts);
    printer.createPdfKitDocument();
    expect(printer.createPdfKitDocument).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
  });
});
```

Jest gives an error:

> TypeError: PdfPrinter is not a constructor

Comment: Use ```PdfPrinter.setFonts(fonts);``` instead of ```const printer = new PdfPrinter(fonts);```

Comment: @Observer thanks, but it gives an error saying `PdfPrinter.setFonts is not a function`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are almost there, if you want to mock the constructor of a node module(`pdfmake`), you need return a `jest.fn()` within the factory function of `jest.mock`.

E.g.
`pdf.js`:

```js
const PdfPrinter = require('pdfmake');
// const fonts = require('./../shared/fonts')
const fonts = {};

const printer = new PdfPrinter(fonts);

const intiateDocCreation = (docDefinition) => printer.createPdfKitDocument(docDefinition);

const finishDocCreation = (pdfDoc, pdfStream) => {
  pdfDoc.pipe(pdfStream);
  pdfDoc.end();
};

module.exports = {
  intiateDocCreation,
  finishDocCreation,
};
```

`pdf.test.js`:

```js
const PdfPrinter = require('pdfmake');

jest.mock('pdfmake', () => {
  const mPdfMake = {
    createPdfKitDocument: jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => ({ a: 'b' })),
  };
  return jest.fn(() => mPdfMake);
});

describe('test', () => {
  test('pdf', () => {
    const fonts = {};
    const printer = new PdfPrinter(fonts);
    printer.createPdfKitDocument();
    expect(printer.createPdfKitDocument).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
  });
});
```

Unit test result:

```sh
 PASS  src/stackoverflow/59250480/pdf.test.js (12.04s)
  test
    ✓ pdf (6ms)

Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        13.694s
```

Comment: The tests pass but the test coverage is still zero for that file

Comment: @ZahraAli Yes, the answer didn't test the functions exported from `pdf.js` module. It just shows the correctly way to mock a constructor